# Segmentation code ignored when a tcolorbox breaks

Tags: tcolorbox

Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,segmentation code={\draw[red]($(segmentation.west)+(1,0)$)--($(segmentation.east)+(-1,0)$);}]
    test
    \tcblower
    Works as expected
   \end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,segmentation code={\draw[red]($(segmentation.west)+(1,0)$)--($(segmentation.east)+(-1,0)$);}]
    \lipsum
    \tcblower
    Does not work as expected
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Unbroken box result:

[image]

Broken box result:

[image]

The goal is to have a tcolorbox with the given segmentation style, e.g. a red line a bit shorter than the box width.

The code works fine if the box does not break, but it seems to be ignored when the box breaks. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I just discovered than I can force the segmentation code after the break putting it inside a `extend freelance last`, but this is not a viable solution since it also changes the appearance of the frame in an undesired way.

Comment: See my comments to Gonzalo Medinas answer.

Comment: To answer 'What am I doing wrong?': Nothing. `segmentation code` changes the code of the *current* skin. That's the `unbroken` one in your case. For the three broken cases `first`, `middle`, `last` there would be own code definitions. `segmentation style` changes the style of the whole break sequence.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for the clarification. How do I put my segmentation code into the `last` or `middle` part of an enhanced broken box? I know how to do it for `freelance`, but not for enhanced.

Comment: Use `skin first is subskin of={enhancedfirst}{segmentation code={...}}`. The same for `middle` and `last`. `enhancedfirst` can be replaced by any skin, e.g. `enhanced` if the box should stay closed. A full example is given on page 170 (v3.02).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `tcolorbox` versions prior to 3.00 (2014/05/08), if you want to use `segmentation code` you need the `freelance` key instead of `enhanced` (in fact, with your original settings, your code doesn't produce the image you showed in the question; the `segmentation code` option is ignored on both cases if `enhanced` is used and not `freelance`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[freelance,breakable,segmentation code={\draw[red]($(segmentation.west)+(1,0)$)--($(segmentation.east)+(-1,0)$);}]
    test
    \tcblower
    Works as expected
   \end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[freelance,breakable,segmentation code={\draw[red]($(segmentation.west)+(1,0)$)--($(segmentation.east)+(-1,0)$);}]
    \lipsum
    \tcblower
    Works as expected
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, using the `freelance` skin changes the way the box behaves at page breaks, so you would need to redo some parts of the box to get the original behaviour.

Starting from `tcolorbox` 3.00 (2014/05/08), `segmentation code` can also be used with `enhanced`, but I'd suggest using `segmentation style` instead of `segmentation code` (this will work in all versions):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  segmentation style={red,solid,shorten >= 1cm,shorten <= 1cm}
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{mybox}
    test
    \tcblower
    Works as expected
   \end{mybox}

    \begin{mybox}
    \lipsum
    \tcblower
    Works as expected
   \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this also changes the appearance of the frame: with the enhanced skin the frame is not closed when the breaks occurs. Compare the result from my original code

Comment: uhm... I tried many times and my code does work in the first case.

Comment: @dcmst which version of `tcolorbox` do you use?

Comment: @dcmst please see my updated answer.

Comment: Just for clarification: starting from `tcolorbox 3.00` (2014/05/08), the `segmentation code` can also be used with `enhanced`; I call it: `freelance` everywhere :-)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer your second code example since it's very elegant. If the broken boxes should appear visibly closed, the key `enhanced` could be replace by `enhanced standard`.

Comment: I am actually on version 3.00, that's why my first code snippet worked.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I've updated my answer adding information about versions. Thanks.

Comment: @dcmst Ah, this explains the different results.