# Segmentation code in tcolorbox does not work when a box breaks

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to make a box with a problem and an answers as below.

[image: When a box unbroken]

When a box is unbroken, I can make this by using "segmentation code".
Otherwise "segmentation code" is ignored, then the box looks like below.

[image: When a box broken]

What should I do to make segmentation code work when a box broken?

Comment: Similar: [Segmentation code ignored when a tcolorbox breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177271). Check especially package author [Thomas F. Sturm's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177271/segmentation-code-ignored-when-a-tcolorbox-breaks?rq=1#comment410551_177271), the example he mentioned is now on page 257, v5.0.2.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you. `skin first is subskin of={enhancedfirst}{segmentation code={...}}` with raw `segmentation code={...}` resolved the problem.